# WEB-INF/classes vs WEB-INF/lib in Jetty 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, spring-transactions

When I package my classes into WEB-INF/classes the Spring @Transactional methods (or any of the methods that match the point-cut definition) that I have do not take part in a transaction. I am met with lots of 'No Hibernate session found, configuration does not allow...' exceptions in the logs. The puzzling thing is that in the stack trace I can see the CGLIB enhanced class so it does appear to be proxied but a new transaction does not seem to be created.

However if I package the ***same classes*** into a jar file and place the jar in WEB-INF/lib, the application works fine! The transaction is created etc., Whats going on here? Why doesn't it work when the classes are under WEB-INF/classes?

The Spring transactional configuration is as below:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="serviceAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">      
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*"/>
        <tx:method name="update*"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*"/>   
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes> 
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>        
    <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* com.example.service.*.*Service*.*(..))"/>            
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="serviceAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut"/>
</aop:config>
```

FWIW, I am using Jetty 7.4 and Spring 3.1.2.

Any clues on what I should be looking for?

**Update:**

I enable Spring transaction logging and I can see that:

```
28 Sep 2012 15:07:16,126 DEBUG NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource:94 - Adding transactional method [save*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
28 Sep 2012 15:07:16,133 DEBUG NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource:94 - Adding transactional method [update*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
28 Sep 2012 15:07:16,134 DEBUG NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource:94 - Adding transactional method [delete*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
28 Sep 2012 15:07:16,136 DEBUG NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource:94 - Adding transactional method [*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly]
```

But when the time comes to actually work in the transactional method, it explodes with exception about not being allowed to create transaction.

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of it whatever is scanning for that annotation is only processing the jars and not the classes under WEB-INF/classes

[edit] jetty is not scanning for these annotations

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I understand Jetty is not scanning for these annotations and its Spring's role to do and being inside the webapp it should have been picked up. But at this point I do not know where to look and hence had thrown in the Jetty tag as well.